# Close window but not app on click of "x" on Mac OS with node webkit

Tags: macos, webkit, node-webkit

Usually on mac, when I close the window it doesn't quit the app but when using node webkit it does quit the app.

Does anyone know a workaround so when I click the "x" it just closes the window but not the app?

Thanks in advance for your help. 
[image]

Comment: #fyi: Still haven't found a solution...

Comment: the new answers are not a complete solution so the bounty will probably expire without a winner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window passes an argument to the callback function if "quit" was clicked, either from the menu bar, or the dock (also on command+Q).
I'm using this code and it works as expected:

```
var gui = require('nw.gui'),
    app = gui.App,
    win = gui.Window.get();

win.on('close', function (action) {
    'quit' === action ?
        app.quit() :
        win.hide();
});

app.on('reopen', function(){
    win.show();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Not a complete solution, all credits goes to Abhishek's answer.

I've improved it to allow user to close the app and not just quit the window.

```
  var hidden = false;
  gui.App.on('reopen', function(){
    hidden = false;
    win.show();
  })

  win.on('close', function(){
    if (hidden == true) {
      gui.App.quit();
    } else {
      win.hide();
      hidden = true;
    }
  });
```

With this trick the first time you click the red button, the window gets closed but still runs in the dock, then, right clicking the icon and clicking **quit** the app is completely closed.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in MAC:

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var window = gui.Window.get();

gui.App.on('reopen', function(){
    window.show();
})

window.on('close', function(){
    window.hide();
});
```

On using above code, If user clicks on close button, it hides window instead of terminating application.
When user clicks on app icon from Dock, GUI `reopen` event is triggered which will show hidden window.
Note: reopen is a MAC specific feature currently.
More details provided in [NodeWebkit App Features](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/App)

Comment: An improvement, but in this way user can't never close the app neither from the menu

Comment: @FezVrasta I think user can close/quit app from menu/dock by doing a right-click on icon and selecting `quit`

Comment: It is working for me in MAC including force quit of app from dock. If in case, app is not closing for you from dock by right-click, then you can add `gui.App.quit()` in close function as mentioned by @FezVrasta

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is a way. I call it <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.
Another way you can do it is <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>power</kbd>